# How to import data folder from Processing library?

Tags: java, processing

I'm creating a Processing library that needs an object and material file stored in the data folder. Here is the file system:

```
nameOfLibFolder
  - library (jar)
  - data (obj/mlt)
```

When I create my library I have the main folder and within the library folder (contains the jar file) and data folder with the assets (obj/mtl files). When I import my library it can use my classes and functions (so it works), but it can't find the object file.

The Processing built-in loadShape function is supposed to read in the model, but it only reads in the file if the data folder is placed in the same directory as the sketch, so how does a library import the data folder automatically into a sketch so I don't get an error loading the file.

Comment: Are the files located inside the jar file, or are they inside the `data` directory of the sketch? Have you tried debugging your library by looking at where it's trying to load the files from?

Comment: Files inside the JAR can't be accessed through the FileSystem. You have to use a ClassLoader to get an InputStream.

Comment: They're inside the data folder. I was following the Processing file system guidelines for a library: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Library-Guidelines. Look at the file structure.

Comment: Do you have an example of a library that used a classloader for data files I could look at?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your library by looking at where it's trying to load the files from?

Comment: Kevin, it was accessing the data folder in the local directory of the sketch. I assumed when creating a library my class would load from it's data directory. Maybe there's another way, but I just accessed the data in the library folder directly to get the right file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by just accessing the data folder directly. I'm not sure how many people have come across this problem before, but loadShape was trying to load from the local data directory in the sketch folder instead of the data folder in the libraries sketchbook.

So just access the data directory from your library directly to get it working.